# How should I design a table where a row can have different columns depending on the type of row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm planning to use the Reddit API and store my saved posts in a database. The saves can be of two types -  Comments or Posts, both of them have few common columns - `author, score, subreddit etc.` and a few columns unique to each category:

comment - `body_text, comment_id, parent_id, etc.`

posts - `selftext,link_url,is_video, etc.`

I decided to separate the 2 categories into their own tables - `Comments table` and `Posts table`. But I don't know how to link these tables to the master table "saves".

My current solution is to have a column `kind` for the type of `save`. The `comment_id` and `post_id` link the `save` to its own table. However, this feels like a messy solution and a bit cumbersome. A `save` can either have a `comment_id` or a `link_id` (but not both or neither), and I also have to manage this constraint.

Saves Table :

```
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------------+---------+
| ID |  Kind   | title |                  post_url                   | author  | comment_id | post_id |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------------+---------+
|  1 | comment | abc   | https://redd.i/redditpostid/redditcommentid | FusionX | 1          | NULL    |
|  2 | post    | xyz   | https://redd.i/redditpostid                 | XnoisuF | NULL       | 1       |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

Post Table :

```
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | is_self |                 selftext                  |       post_url        | num_comments |  thumbnail   |
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | no      | NULL                                      | i.imgur.com/xyz.jpg   |         1020 | someimageurl |
|  2 | yes     | "some random selftext of variable length" | redd.it/redditpostid/ |           10 |              |
+----+---------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment table:

```
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| ID |            body_html            |  reddit_comment_id  |  reddit_parent_id  |
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | comment text of variable length | <reddit comment id> | <reddit parent id> |
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

(reddit ID's are different from my table's own IDs and are only relevant at reddit's end)

Is there a better way to design this database?

Comment: Does `saves` have to be table or can it be view?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm not sure, I'm quite new to databases. I want to maintain the order of the saves (i.e. post1,post2,coment1,post3,comment2) in the order of their serialized ID.  Will that be the case with views?

Comment: Why do you not use inheritance? It seems appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should move the owning side of the relation to the two other tables.
So instead of having `comment_id` and `post_id` columns in `saves` table, have a `saves_id` column in `post` table and `comment` table.